# pass optional block to an inline lambda

Tags: ruby

I have created a lambda called `imap_query` below that wraps a call to a method call that I need to make twice in the code below.

The first time I call the `imap_query` lambda, I do not want to pass a block in as I only want the return value of the `google.email.find` function call.

The second time I call the `imap_query` lambda, I want to pass a block.

```
  def process_emails(user, google, folder)
    since_time = Net::IMAP.format_date 1.day.ago

    imap_query = -> {
                      google.email.find(mailbox: folder, read_only: true, count: max_emails, keys: [ 'RECENT', 'SINCE', since_time ])
                     }

    @email_total = imap_query().size

    return finish_sync(user) if @email_total == 0

    # how do I pass a block to the imap_query lambda
    imap_query.call() do |mail, imap, uid|
      update_progress user
      yield mail, imap, uid
    end
  end
```

What I am struggling with is:

1. How to declare the lambda with an optional block parameter.
2. How to call the lambda and pass a block in, if I want to pass one in.

Comment: Why do you want to use a lambda instead of a method?

Comment: there really is no good reason apart from my curiosity, a method would be fine, how would I pass the optional block to a method?

What I am trying to avoid is duplicating the argument list to google.email.find

Answer (score 1):

Every method in ruby can take a block. When writing

```
def foo(i)
  puts i
end
```

you can also call

```
foo 1 do puts "a block" end
```

without an error.

You can also use the [block_given?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given?) Kernel method which identifies if a block is passed to the method or not.

```
def bar(i)
  puts i
  if block_given?
    puts "a block"
    yield
  else
    puts "no block"
  end
end
```

where

```
bar 1
#=> 1
#=> no block

bar 1 do puts "Yippie a block" end
#=> 1
#=> a block
#=> Yippie a block
```

an alternative way of doing that is with the `&block` *argument*

```
def baz(i, &block)
  puts i
  block.call unless block.nil?
end

baz 1
#=> 1
baz 1 do puts "a block" end
#=> 1
#=> a block
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question while trying to do something similar.  A couple comments:

a) I'm confused by the original question because the second call to imap_query is given a block which is expecting arguments, but it isn't clear to me where the arguments are be passed.

b) The imap_query lambda uses a 'max_emails' variable that I don't see declared anywhere.

Regarding the questions:

1. From my reading of [Proc#call](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call), passing a block to #call on a Proc object is not supported
2. While I don't think it is possible to pass a block to a Proc, it *is* possible to pass an (optional) Proc to another Proc (similar to @xlembouras' last example, but with a Proc vs. a Method)

For example:

```
>> a = ->(b=nil) { puts :a; b.call if b }
>> b = ->{ puts :b }
>> a.call()
a
=> nil
>> a.call(b)
a
b
=> nil
```

and:

```
>> a = ->(b=nil) { puts :a; b.call(1,2,3) if b }
=> #<Proc:0x007fc573a917e0@(irb):41 (lambda)>
>> b = ->(*args){ puts :b; puts args.join(',') }
=> #<Proc:0x007fc5734088d8@(irb):42 (lambda)>
>> a.call()
a
=> nil
>> a.call(b)
a
b
1,2,3
=> nil
```